# Why $exp(0_{T_eG})=e$, where $exp$ is the exponential map of a Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I wonder if this fact is true:

I consider the exponential map of a Lie group $G$.
$$exp: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G.$$
Is it true that $exp(0_{T_eG})=e$, where $e$ is the identity element of $G$?

Can someone explain me why?
Is it because the one parameter local subgroup associated to $0_{T_eH}$ is constantly equal to $e$ by definition of integral curve?
Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, $\exp(0)=e$ and your explanation is correct.